# How can I test antd's useMessage() hook with React Testing Library?

Tags: react-hooks, antd, react-testing-library

Testing the `useMessage()` hook

Hello. I need to test antd's `useMessage()` hook with React Testing Library. I'm new to testing and don't know how to solve my problem. You can show on the example of one of the methods, for example `messageApi.info()`. Please help me.

https://ant.design/components/message

Now i have this code:

```
test('info message', async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useMessage(), {
    wrapper: Wrapper
  });
  const messageApi = result.current[0];
  const messageInfo = () =>
    messageApi.info({
      content: 'test'
    });
});
```

How can I test that a message appears with the text 'test'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my question.
So in order to test the appearance of a message with a certain text, you need to do this:

```
test('info message', async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useMessage());
  const [messageApi, contextHolder] = result.current;
  render(
      <Container>
        {contextHolder}
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            messageApi.info({
              content: <div data-testid="test-id">Some message</div>
            })
          }
        >
          Info
        </button>
      </Container>
  );
  const button = await screen.findByRole('button');
  fireEvent.click(button);
  const message = await screen.findByTestId('test-id');
  expect(message).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(message).toHaveTextContent('Some message');
});
```